# Concisely removing a DOM element if it exists?

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

I'm currently writing a browser script (for use in Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey) (and learning JS in the process!), and I have ***a lot*** of occurrences like this:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#unwantedButton");
if (btn) {
    btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
}
```

That is, I want a certain element to be removed, if it exists.

Is there any way to write this more concisely and elegantly? That would save me a lot of lines in this project, and most importantly, teach me some JS best practice. :-)

Thank you for helping a JS noob!

Comment: Now that I think of it, I should probably make it a function, or loop through an array of unwanted elements. I leave this open anyway, as I'd like to know your thoughts and ideas. I'm sure there are better ways to write this! Thank you!

Comment: don't use queryselector, just document.getElementById("unwantedButton") is simpler

Comment: Thank you @SuperStormer. I actually did use that at first, but switched to `querySelector` as that is shorter than `getElementById`. Why is it better? I also sometimes have to access elements based on class, and that was easier with `querySelector` than with `getElementsByClass(...)[0]`, at least for me with my limited knowledge of JS and its standard functions.

Comment: It's hard to say which one is better because it depends on the use case. There is a bit wider browser support (e.g. IE6) for `getElementById` but it's unlikely to be significant in your case. I would choose `querySelector` because of flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rewrite the code in several places, you can put it in a function (and use `remove()`:

```
function removeIfExists (selector) {
  var x = document.querySelector(selector)
  if (x) x.remove()
}
```

Then you can call it all over the place:

```
removeIfExists("#some-unwanted-element")
```

You can also use it if you have a list of known elements you don't want:

```
var badElements = [ ".foo", "#bar", "#etc" ]
badElements.forEach(removeIfExists)
```

Comment: Thank you, Zac! This is perfect. Great learning. And thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as a function for multiple elements

```
const removeElements = refs => document.querySelectorAll(refs)
                                .forEach(el=>{if(!!el) el.remove()})
```

usage :

```
removeElements('#unwantedButton')
```

or

```
removeElements('.foo, #bar, #etc')
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot that `querySelectorAll` can take a comma-separated list!